# Drupal Views Search: Creating an Exposed Filter with Checkbox Options

Tags: views, search

Using basic search module and Views to make a search interface.

When I create an exposed filter for a field with multiple options I only have the option to choose 'dropdown' or 'autocomplete' for the filter settings.

Is there a way to make the filter display the options to users with checkboxes rather than a dropdown menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module should help you.
[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: is this for drupal 7, i cant't find those options on drupal 8 after installig module and use it in view